# Create Linux System User with Password from Java

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

I want to create a Linux system user with password from my Java application. I currently use following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = 
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/sbin/useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 " + password + ") " + username);
```

The unix command `useradd` requires the user to be sudoer/enter a password, so I added the user to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
myUser  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd
```

Creating a user directly from command line (with `sudo`, but without entering a password)  works. But if I create a user from my Java application, I get:

```
[info] application - useradd: Permission denied.
[info] application - useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

When adding `sudo` to the process string (`"sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 " + password + ") " + username)`), I don't get any (error) output, but the user is not created either.

Edit:

`/etc/sudoers`-File

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myUser  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The Java application is executed by `myUser`

Comment: Make sure the "Defaults    requiretty" is changed to "Defaults    !requiretty" This will allow you to run commands with sudo in the background with no tty.

Comment: Adding this string to "/etc/sudoers" doesn't help me. With "sudo" before "/usr/sbin/useradd" the console output asks for a password. Without "sudo" I get the same error as above.

Comment: Change you line to: myUser  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd

Comment: Actually it didn't work. It just worked because I executed some sudo command and restarted the server afterwards, so I guess I was still logged in as super user. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you execute sudo useradd as myuser from the command line with no password?

Comment: No, it doesn't work either. Going to figure this problem out first before adding users programmatically.